# How to style this views in drupal 7 /custom content type/?

Tags: php, html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I`ve created custom content type with fields: title, text, image, link. The machine names of fields are: field_logo, title, field_info_txt, field_link_logo. The custom content type i called is catlist. The image field contains logo images, that also is link (external url).

http://s22.postimg.org/d7fmzzio1/now.jpg

In the moment is this, but i want to style it with CSS or views module in drupal, to look inline, not every logo image in another row(one above another). I I want them floated left. How can i make this. I want something like this:

http://s23.postimg.org/t6on8z13v/want.jpg

Maybe i have to make --catlist.tpl.php  theme for this content type, to make my css styling, but i dont`t know php, only html and CSS. How can i make this, and is it possible with views only. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Views module you can assign a class to those fields from the Views interface:

[image]

and then apply `display: inline-block` or `float:left` to that class to position the element as you need it. In this way you don't need to create any tpl file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to have full controll over the template of a Custom Content Type without some Coding.

The most convenient way, as you've already suggested on your own, would be to create a own template. If you can afford to spend some time, you could learn the basics of PHP (you don't need to know *that* much) on a page like codecademy.com

For further Information on how to style a custom content type you can look at the official example from drupal.org

https://drupal.org/node/266817